# Displaying Marker Groups in Google Map for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

My map (Google Map SDK) displays a large number of locations markers. To organize them into clusters I used Distance-based Clustering -- simple. Now, the challenge is to define the right business logic to set the correct zoom level to display **the marker clusters**.

See the ENCLOSED picture.

I'd like the markers rendered on the map to be clustered into **AS MANY groups AS** to fit the bounds of the map. For example, if a single cluster is about to be created by Google Map SDK, break it up and create *as many clusters as* to fit the viewable map area tightly. Do not show 1 cluster, zoomed out.

In you answer please be specific, which approach would you use and why. How would you set the right zoom-level?

```
Grid-based Clustering
Distance-based Clustering
Viewport Marker Management
Fusion Tables
MarkerClusterer
MarkerManager
```

**VISUAL REPRESENTATION: Show B but not A:**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B70UaoIrLEeLTUxMZXBCTTRIY1U/edit?usp=sharing